# Transação com chave estrangeira em C# e Entity-

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Galera, na minha aplicação tenho a classe Context que possui o DbSet de Compras e DbSet de Produtos.
Acontece que na minha tabela no BD, Compras possui uma FK que pega o ID de Produtos na coluna FK_ID_PROD.

Pergunta 1: Como ficará o mapeamento dessa coluna no Entity?

Pergunta2: Devo, nessa classe "Compras", criar uma lista do tipo Produtos ou apenas uma lista de Inteiros e armazenar os IDs dos produtos?

Obrigado!

Comment: Carlos o que você exatamente está querendo fazer?

Comment: De uma olhada  no  exemplo  que eu  fiz, não deu para postar aqui

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hLbwL0

Comment: Marcos, muito obrigado pela ajuda man! Era exatamente isso que eu queria.